# Emails are not delivered when using NextJs and NodeMailer on Vercel hosting

Tags: email, next.js, smtp, nodemailer

I use NextJs and NodeMail to send messages from the site.

Locally, the code works fine, and the emails are delivered to the email inbox. But I'm using hosting from Vercel where sending the email doesn't happen. Vercel logs also show POST request.

And all Environment Variables are saved on the Vercel hosting.

How can I fix this problem?

Code:

**API**

```
export const sendContactForm = async (data) =>
fetch("/api/contact", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", Accept: "application/json" },
}).then((res) => {
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error("Failed to send message")
    return res.json()
})



import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

const email = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL
const pass = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_PASSWORD

export const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
        user: { email },
        pass: { pass },
    },
    secure: true
})

export const mailOptions = {
    from: { email },
    to: { email },

}
```

**Contact.js**

```
export default function (req, res) {

    let nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        port: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_PORT,
        host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_HOST,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
        },
        secure: true,
    })
    const mailData = {
        from: `${req.body.email}`,
        to: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL,
        subject: `Message From ${req.body.email}`,
        text: "Message " + req.body.message + " | Sent from: " + req.body.name + " | Phone: " + req.body.phone,
        html: `<p>Name: ${req.body.name}</p><p>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</p><p>Sent from: ${req.body.email}</p><div>${req.body.message}</div>`
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (err, info) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        else
            console.log(info)
    })

    res.status(200).json({ success: true })
}
```

**Nodemailer.js**

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

const email = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL
const pass = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EMAIL_PASSWORD

export const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
        user: { email },
        pass: { pass },
    },
    secure: true
})

export const mailOptions = {
    from: { email },
    to: { email },

}
```

**And then the code when you click on the send button**

```
 const onSubmit = async () => {
        setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            isLoading: true,
        }))

        try {
            await sendContactForm(values)
            setTouched({})
            setState(initState)
        } catch (error) {
            setState((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                isLoading: false,
                error: error.message,
            }))
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: did you solved this isse with nodemailer on vercel ? if so could you please tell us whats should get change